# Program to visualise and/or model socket connections

Tags: gratis, linux, software-development, modeling, visual-design

I am looking for a program to visually model a computer system that has many socket connections between its component parts.

Its socket connections may be internal to a program, communicate to programs on the same machine, or communicate to programs on remote machine(s).

I would like to be able to visually layout a systems communication map to model this aspect of a system.

I realise something like DIA will probably be my best option, however I was wondering if a more specialised option was available.

Comment: Do you want to s/w to detect the socket connections? When you mention DIA it makes me think that you are just asking for a drawing program.

Comment: I would like a program to visualise and preferably model the connections, id prefer not to just use dia and draw it all out, hence the request for a specialised program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you should consider [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/)?

You write [simple text files](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/lang.html), then run therm though the tool to draw diagrams of various sorts.  Here's their example of a (very large) network (there are many more examples in their [gallery](http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery.php)).

Note that the input text file was generated by a network scanner tool. I have often coded similar programs to generate the input to such drawing packages (GraphViz, Msg-Generator, etc) and you could later do this with a port-scanner on your running system.

[image: Network map]