# Drawing revision / integration graphs

Tags: graphs, subversion, diagram

Does anyone know of a free tool for easy drawing of revision or integration graphs? 
I don't mean from existing revision information in the SVN repository, but for **planning future integration**. 
Something like the image below:
[image]

I have tools like Visio and yEd, but I wonder if there is a fit-for-purpose tool out there.

Comment: Mentioning SVN, I know there's a plugin for Edgewall's *Trac* building similar graphs. Not that I want you to check that, but: that plugin AFAIK utilizes [Graphviz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphviz). So while waiting for answers, you could use that keyword with a web search. Count it just as a pointer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I like yEdit, I think that http://www.graphviz.org/ would be the perfect answer, as @Izzy mentions in his comment.

I have been using it for years. It is excellent for drawing any diagram with nodes (trees, network diagrams, sate machines, etc, etc, etc)

Just take a look at the [gallery](http://www.graphviz.org/gallery/).

It is very stable, very widely used, and well supported. It is also free and cross platform (you didn't state your o/s).

As stated in my well received previous answers recommending the tool, [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/16864/program-to-visualise-and-or-model-socket-connections/16878#16878,), [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3264/software-to-draw-the-data-flow-of-a-program/19313#19313), and [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17711/tree-graph-visualisation-convert-table-to-a-graph/17717#17717), you write a simple text file, then run it though the tool to draw diagrams of various sorts. There are a plethora of options to configure the layout of the digram which is produced.

Here is a very simple example taken from the [examples page](http://graphs.grevian.org/example) of the site:

Input:

```
graph {  
        a -- b;   
        b -- c;   
        a -- c;   
        d -- c;   
        e -- c;   
        e -- a;   
   }
```

Output:

[image]

I am sure that you can see how this can meet your needs. Just tweak it for line colour, shape of nodes, etc

Comment: I've used Graphviz a lot before, just hadn't thought of using it for this. Thanks for the recommendation!!